# Specify -javaagent Option in Manifest

Tags: java, jar, manifest, instrumentation, javaagents

To tell the JVM to invoke a Java Instrumentation agent before the main class of a Jar file, you usually have to invoke it with a command option:

```
java -javaagent:agent.jar program.jar
```

Having to type this out every time is pretty inconvenient, so is there a way to specify the agent in the `program.jar` manifest?

```
# program.jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
...
Java-Agent: agent.jar
```

Comment: At the end of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19912148/2711488) is a sample code using the Attach API to attach to itself, in other words, starting itself as Java agent. It’s main purpose is to get hand on the `Instrumentation` implementation instance. If that’s your goal, you’re already done. If you know for sure that your code will be contained in a jar file already having the necessary `Agent-Class: ` manifest entry, you could simplify that solution by skipping the creation of the dummy jar file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java 9 adds the Launcher-Agent-Class attribute which can be used on executable JAR files to start an agent before the main class is loaded.

Comment: Unfortunately, `Launcher-Agent-Class` only supports a single agent and no option string like the command line does. But there is [Agent Embedder Maven Plugin](https://github.com/dev-aspectj/agent-embedder-maven-plugin?tab=readme-ov-file), which adds those features and even for the simple case (single agent, no argument) just makes it easy to package an agent into your JAR during the build. Maybe, you want to give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no such option. As an alternative, you can use the attach API to attach a Java agent dynamically. This does however have some limitations, e.g. it typically only works on a JVM that is distributed with a JDK.

For a convenient API for attaching agents, have a look at [Byte Buddy Agent](http://bytebuddy.net/javadoc/1.5.6/net/bytebuddy/agent/ByteBuddyAgent.html).

Comment: Is there a way to specify an agent Premain class in the same Jar file, so that I don't have a extra Jar for it in the first place (I.e., having the content of agent.jar in program.jar)?

Comment: Yes, of course. you can combine the jar files by adding the `Premain-Class` and `Main-Class` headers to the same manifest and the run `java -javaagent:program.jar program.jar`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that still requires me to put the `-javaagent` option :(

Comment: This you can only avoid by programmatic attachment.