# Is there any way to judge whether a class has been loaded into jvm?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot

Is there any way to judge whether a class has been loaded into jvm?
In my opinion,I think the way is `findClass` ,is that right?

Comment: This depends on what you requirements are. Is it when the class is searched for, loaded via byte code and thus has a `.class` object, or when it's initialised?

Comment: May be it is loaded,and then is deleted .So I think I can not judge from the object class,such as aop mechanism.

Comment: The real question is probably: why do you think that matters? In other words: what is the problem you intend to solve by doing such a judgement?

Comment: I was asked  from an interview.I still can not figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I have not done this. But it seems that it would be possible via `getAllLoadedClasses()` in the [Instrumentation API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html).

But then you would still need to start the JVM with your `agent`.

Comment: Depending on the JVM, you may load agents after the start dynamically, e.g. via the Attach API. At the end of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19912148/2711488) is an example program that attaches to its own JVM to load itself as agent to finally get hands on the `Instrumentation` API.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on class loader logging with `-verbose:class` and read the log.

Comment: what if you have already started the JVM and it is running at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jdk tool,such as JConsole.