# How to remove method body at runtime with ASM 5.2

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

I'm trying to remove the method body of `test()` in the following program so that nothing is printed to the Console. I'm using using ASM 5.2 but everything I've tried doesn't seem to have any effect.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong and also point me to some up-to-date tutorials or documentation on ASM? Almost everything Iv'e found on Stackoverflow and the ASM website seems outdated and/or unhelpful.

```
public class BytecodeMods {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        disableMethod(BytecodeMods.class.getMethod("test"));
        test();
    }

    public static void test() {
        System.out.println("This is a test");
    }

    private static void disableMethod(Method method) {
        new MethodReplacer()
                .visitMethod(Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC | Opcodes.ACC_STATIC, method.getName(), Type.getMethodDescriptor(method), null, null);
    }

    public static class MethodReplacer extends ClassVisitor {

        public MethodReplacer() {
            super(Opcodes.ASM5);
        }

        @Override
        public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: How should your code have an effect on the class? All you are doing, is to invoke the method `MethodReplacer.visitMethod` that you have implemented yourself as `return null;`. How could a single invocation of method that always just returns `null` have an effect on anything?

Comment: Haha I just realized that, now I feel stupid. I have no idea how to use the ASM library. Any help would be appreciated. Is it the fact that the class is already loaded and I'm trying to modify it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are not supposed to invoke the methods of a visitor directly.

The correct way to use a `ClassVisitor`, is to create a [`ClassReader`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/?org/objectweb/asm/ClassReader.html) with the class file bytes of the class you’re interested in and pass the class visitor to the its [`accept`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassReader.html#accept-org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor-int-) method. Then, all the `visit` methods will be called by the class reader according to the artifacts found in the class file.

In this regard, you should not consider the documentation outdated, just because it refers to an older version number. E.g. [this document](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/tutorial-asm-2.0.html) describes that process correctly and it speaks for the library that no fundamental change was necessary between the versions 2 and 5.

Still, visiting a class does not change it. It helps analyzing it and perform actions when encountering a certain artifact. Note that returning `null` is not an actual action.

If you want to create a modified class, you need a [`ClassWriter`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/?org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.html) to produce the class. A `ClassWriter` implements `ClassVisitor`, also [class visitors can be chained](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor.html#ClassVisitor-int-org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor-), so you can easily create a custom visitor delegating to a writer, that will produce a class file identical to the original one, unless you override a method to intercept the recreation of a feature.

But note that returning `null` from `visitMethod` does more than removing the code, it will remove the method entirely. Instead, you have to return a special visitor for the specific method which will reproduce the method but ignore the old code and create a sole `return` instruction (you are allowed to omit the last `return` statement in source code, but not the `return` instruction in the byte code).

```
private static byte[] disableMethod(Method method) {
    Class<?> theClass = method.getDeclaringClass();
    ClassReader cr;
    try { // use resource lookup to get the class bytes
        cr = new ClassReader(
            theClass.getResourceAsStream(theClass.getSimpleName()+".class"));
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
    }
    // passing the ClassReader to the writer allows internal optimizations
    ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(cr, 0);
    cr.accept(new MethodReplacer(
            cw, method.getName(), Type.getMethodDescriptor(method)), 0);

    byte[] newCode = cw.toByteArray();
    return newCode;
}

static class MethodReplacer extends ClassVisitor {
    private final String hotMethodName, hotMethodDesc;

    MethodReplacer(ClassWriter cw, String name, String methodDescriptor) {
        super(Opcodes.ASM5, cw);
        hotMethodName = name;
        hotMethodDesc = methodDescriptor;
    }

    // invoked for every method
    @Override
    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(
        int access, String name, String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions) {

        if(!name.equals(hotMethodName) || !desc.equals(hotMethodDesc))
            // reproduce the methods we're not interested in, unchanged
            return super.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions);

        // alter the behavior for the specific method
        return new ReplaceWithEmptyBody(
            super.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions),
            (Type.getArgumentsAndReturnSizes(desc)>>2)-1);
    }
}
static class ReplaceWithEmptyBody extends MethodVisitor {
    private final MethodVisitor targetWriter;
    private final int newMaxLocals;

    ReplaceWithEmptyBody(MethodVisitor writer, int newMaxL) {
        // now, we're not passing the writer to the superclass for our radical changes
        super(Opcodes.ASM5);
        targetWriter = writer;
        newMaxLocals = newMaxL;
    }

    // we're only override the minimum to create a code attribute with a sole RETURN

    @Override
    public void visitMaxs(int maxStack, int maxLocals) {
        targetWriter.visitMaxs(0, newMaxLocals);
    }

    @Override
    public void visitCode() {
        targetWriter.visitCode();
        targetWriter.visitInsn(Opcodes.RETURN);// our new code
    }

    @Override
    public void visitEnd() {
        targetWriter.visitEnd();
    }

    // the remaining methods just reproduce meta information,
    // annotations & parameter names

    @Override
    public AnnotationVisitor visitAnnotation(String desc, boolean visible) {
        return targetWriter.visitAnnotation(desc, visible);
    }

    @Override
    public void visitParameter(String name, int access) {
        targetWriter.visitParameter(name, access);
    }
}
```

The custom `MethodVisitor` does not get chained to the method visitor returned by the class writer. Configured this way, it will not replicate the code automatically. Instead, performing no action will be the default and only our explicit invocations on the `targetWriter` will produce code.

At the end of the process, you have a `byte[]` array containing the changed code in the class file format. So the question is, what to do with it.

The easiest, most portable thing you can do, is to create a new `ClassLoader`, which creates a new `Class` from these bytes, which has the same name (as we didn’t change the name), but is distinct from the already loaded class, because it has a different defining class loader. We can access such dynamically generated class only through Reflection:

```
public class BytecodeMods {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        byte[] code = disableMethod(BytecodeMods.class.getMethod("test"));
        new ClassLoader() {
            Class<?> get() { return defineClass(null, code, 0, code.length); }
        }   .get()
            .getMethod("test").invoke(null);
    }

    public static void test() {
        System.out.println("This is a test");
    }

    …
```

In order to make this example do something more notable than doing nothing, you could alter the message instead,

using the following `MethodVisitor`

```
static class ReplaceStringConstant extends MethodVisitor {
    private final String matchString, replaceWith;

    ReplaceStringConstant(MethodVisitor writer, String match, String replacement) {
        // now passing the writer to the superclass, as most code stays unchanged
        super(Opcodes.ASM5, writer);
        matchString = match;
        replaceWith = replacement;
    }

    @Override
    public void visitLdcInsn(Object cst) {
        super.visitLdcInsn(matchString.equals(cst)? replaceWith: cst);
    }
}
```

by changing

```
        return new ReplaceWithEmptyBody(
            super.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions),
            (Type.getArgumentsAndReturnSizes(desc)>>2)-1);
```

to

```
        return new ReplaceStringConstant(
            super.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions),
            "This is a test", "This is a replacement");
```

---

If you want to change the code of an already loaded class or intercept it right before being loaded into the JVM, you have to use the Instrumentation API.

The byte code transformation itself doesn’t change, you’ll have to pass the source bytes into the `ClassReader` and get the modified bytes back from the `ClassWriter`. Methods like [`ClassFileTransformer.transform(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/ClassFileTransformer.html#transform-java.lang.ClassLoader-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-java.security.ProtectionDomain-byte:A-) will already receive the bytes representing the current form of the class (there might have been previous transformations) and return the new bytes.

The problem is, this API isn’t generally available to Java applications. It’s available for so-called Java Agents, which must have been either, started together with the JVM via startup options or get loaded dynamically in an implementation-specific way, e.g. via the Attach API.

The [package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html#package.description) describes the general structure of Java Agents and the related command line options.

At the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19912148/2711488) is a program demonstrating how to use the Attach API to attach to your own JVM to load a dummy Java Agent that will give the program access to the Instrumentation API. Considering the complexity, I think, it became apparent, that the actual code transformation and turning the code into a runtime class or using it to replace a class on the fly, are two different tasks that have to collaborate, but whose code you usually want to keep separated.

Comment: Thank you! I'm getting an error though: `ClassFormatError: Arguments can't fit into locals in class file` the method I tried to disable has 2 parameters.

Comment: This code is tailored to the example of the question, where the method is `static`. If it is not, you have to change the term `(Type.getArgumentsAndReturnSizes(desc)>>2)-1` removing the `-1` (the `-1` was exactly for removing the space of the `this` reference). So for an instance method, `Type.getArgumentsAndReturnSizes(desc)>>2` will already calculate the locals for ‹`this`+arguments›.

Comment: I tried that lol. I used `new ClassWriter(reader, ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS)` and I think that fixed it but the method still isn't being erased. The method is in an interface with the attributes `static void`.  If I try disabling the method before the class is loaded I get a `NoClassDefFoundError` when I try to get the `Method` instance. The class is contained in a separate jar and will by default be loaded by a different classloader.

Comment: Well, `COMPUTE_MAXS` forces ASM to recalculate the max stack and local values, so it compensates mistakes at this place. I used `super.visitMaxs(0, newMaxLocals)` where it should be `targetWriter.visitMaxs(0, newMaxLocals)`. I fixed it in my answer, so that should work now, even without `COMPUTE_MAXS`.

Comment: Acquiring a `Method` object from a `Class` implies its loading. But note that for ASM, only the name and signature strings are required to match a method. These strings are extracted in the expression `new MethodReplacer(cw, method.getName(), Type.getMethodDescriptor(method))`, but you can use other ways to get to these strings. The name is the easiest part, that’s the same string you pass to `Class.getMethod(…)`. The descriptor can be constructed with `Type.getMethodDescriptor(Type, Type...)` or you learn [the syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3.3)…

Comment: Ok. It's not throwing any errors but it's still not working. Is it possible another class loader is still loading the original class?

Comment: You may put an initializer `static { System.out.println("class initialized"); }` into the class. Or better `static { Thread.dumpStack(); }` to find the trigger…

Comment: Yeah... I don't think this is possible in my case without retransformation. I think I'll be able to figure that out though. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

The easier way is to create a MethodNode instance and replace the body with a new InsnList. First, you need the original class representation. You can get it just like @Holger suggested.

```
Class<?> originalClass = method.getDeclaringClass();
ClassReader classReader;
try {
    cr = new ClassReader(
        originalClass.getResourceAsStream(originalClass.getSimpleName()+".class"));
} catch(IOException e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
}
```

Then create a ClassNode and replace the method body.

```
//Create the CLassNode
ClassNode classNode = new ClassNode();
classReader.accept(classNode,0);

//Search for the wanted method
final List<MethodNode> methods = classNode.methods;
for(MethodNode methodNode: methods){
    if(methodNode.name.equals("test")){
        //Replace the body with a RETURN opcode
        InsnList insnList = new InsnList();
        insnList.add(new InsnNode(Opcodes.RETURN));
        methodNode.instructions = insnList;
    }
}
```

Before generating the new class, you will need a ClassLoader with a public defineClass() method. Just like this.

```
public class GenericClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

    public Class<?> defineClass(String name, byte[] b) {
        return defineClass(name, b, 0, b.length);
    }

}
```

Now you can generate the actual class.

```
//Generate the Class
ClassWriter classWriter = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES | ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS);
classNode.accept(classWriter);

//Define the representation
GenericClassLoader classLoader = new GenericClassLoader();
Class<?> modifiedClass = classLoader.defineClass(classNode.name, classWriter.toByteArray());
```