# Attach to current VM using com.sun.tools

Tags: java, jvm, javaagents

Is it possible to get the VM the program is currently running in? I know there is a `VirtualMachine.list()` method but I can't figure out how to find the right one. I can't search for a specific `displayName` since it's dynamic.

Is there another way to find the right VM?

Comment: See the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19912148/2711488) for a complete example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ID of the VM to attach to is a process ID (pid). So, you just need to [find pid of the current JVM process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842/how-can-a-java-program-get-its-own-process-id).

Here is a way to do this:

```
String jvmName = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
String jvmPid = jvmName.substring(0, jvmName.indexOf('@'));

VirtualMachine self = VirtualMachine.attach(jvmPid);
```

Note: since JDK 9 attaching to current process requires setting the system property:

```
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
```